# Can Augmented psionic powers be made permanent, maybe via Incarnate?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

I'm creating a psion were-eagle (for an all were-creatures campaign). While looking for reliable, lightweight armor options to offset my psion's squishiness I'm considering whether *inertial armor* could be made to work.

Can an augmented psionic power be made permanent with [*incarnate*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/incarnate.htm), and does it permanently retain the augmentation? For instance, can I have a permanent AC bonus from an [*inertial armor*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/inertialArmor.htm) that’s higher than the default +4?

Comment: Please keep questions on-point; we don’t need to know *why* you want to do this, it’s not relevant to the question.

Comment: Looking at the Incarnate ability, it doesn't list "Inertial Armor" as a valid spell. Is it houseruled or am I missing something?

Comment: @Novian Though, you never asked about it so I removed it from the question, but I will point out that most flying creatures cannot fly if they are above a light load. Heavy armor may be difficult to use unless you have quite-high strength for a psion.

Comment: Sorry. i was in a bit of a rush, and no....i dont have a high strength score...in fact mine is low even for a psion. at 4.

Comment: @KRyan [Good questions have context](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx); but you're right that they shouldn't have a long ramble of context.

Answer (score 8):

The power *incarnate* can only affect a specific set of powers:

- *Aura sight*
- *Conceal thoughts*
- *Danger sense*
- *Detect psionics*
- *Detect remote viewing*
- *Detect teleportation*
- *Elfsight*
- *Know direction and location*
- *My light*
- *Psionic darkvision*
- *Ubiquitous vision*

Notably, *inertial armor* is not on the list, so you cannot make it permanent with *incarnate*.

Some of these powers *can* be augmented, however, so the base question is still valid. The rules don’t explicitly address this issue, but based on how *incarnate* works, I’m reasonably certain that it does retain the augmentation of the original power. You first manifest the power you want (with the Augmentation you want), and then manifest *incarnate*. All *incarnate* does in this case is change the other power’s duration to Permanent. So nothing else about the power – including its augmentation and the effects of that – changes.

As for other ways to “making *inertial armor* work,” the hour/level duration on the power pretty much does that for you. If you really want, you could apply Extend Power to it to make it last 2 hours/level. By the time you manage even a moderate manifester level, that’s going to last a *really* long time – more than long enough to get yourself in trouble and out again if necessary.

Comment: D20PFSRD lists a power called "Converse" as well in the incarnate list. Yet the power doesn't seem to exist in D20PFSRD, the PDF Psionics Unleashed, or Ultimate Psionics, but all sources have the references. Is there errata dropping it?

Comment: Is the new "Converse" actually "Natural Linguist"? It's the right power level according to the incarate costs.